# Modification of a stochastic process and complete filtration

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, filtrations

I consider $B_t$ $t\in[0,T]$ a (real valued) stochastic process  adapted for the filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ and $\bar{B}_t$ à modification of $B_t$. I would like to show that $\bar{B}_t$ is adapted for the completion of $\mathcal{F}_t$ that is $\bar{\mathcal{F}}_t$.

Here is my attempt : Let $t\in[0,T]$ and $A$ be a borel set. We know that $\bar{B}_t = B_t$ a.s.

Then we see that $\big\{ \omega\in \Omega : \bar{B}_t(\omega)\in A \big\}\cap\big\{\omega\in \Omega : \bar{B}_t(\omega) = B_t(\omega)\big\}\in\bar{\mathcal{F}}_t$ as it is the set where $\bar{B}_t$ and $B_t$ coincides.

In the other hand $\big\{ \omega\in \Omega : \bar{B}_t(\omega)\in A \big\}\cap\big\{\omega\in \Omega : \bar{B}_t(\omega) \neq B_t(\omega)\big\}$ corresponds to a null set so it is in $\bar{\mathcal{F}}_t$.

So the union of these two sets which is $\big\{ \omega\in \Omega : \bar{B}_t(\omega)\in A \big\}$ is also in $\bar{\mathcal{F}}_t$ since it is a sigma algebra.

I would like to know if it is correct please and if not what can I improve ?

Thank you a lot !

Comment: What is your definition of modification? That $P(B_t=\overline{B}_t)=1$? To make statements about probability of sets, say $P(A)$, you need to be working on some background measure space on which the set $A$ is measurable. A modification would then normally be defined on the same probability space, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @JoseAvilez Thank your for your comment ! A modification $Y$ of $X$ is a stochastic proceds defined on the same probability space such that for all $t\in T$ we have $X_t=Y_t$ a.s.

Comment: then there is nothing to prove, as they are defined on the same measure space, hence are adapted

Comment: @JoseAvilez Thank you for your comment. To see that it is adapted I really needed to write the argument used in my post even if I conceive that we can infer it would be the case . You are saying that it is direct, is what I have written false or am I missing something ? I